# Script that runs when voice detected on the mic

Tags: sound, bash, scripts

I'd like to simulate a 'voice activation feature': when vox is detected on the microphone, the script should press the button and then release when the speech is over.

Anyone has one?

Comment: You would need something to run in the background to detect the right combination of words etc to run whatever first. If you want to operate a actual button, this likely is outside the scope of this site...

Comment: @Wilf, just voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way through the verbose output of the `arecord`:

```
arecord -D pulse -c 2 -d 0 -f S16_LE -vvv /dev/null
```

Just need to add `xte` to do a keypress.